# Jquery: Hide a text box and then show it

Tags: jquery

I am very new to jquery. I have a major doubt here. Basically I wanna do a recursion kind of thing in jquery! I have a textbox inside a div. The user would enter his name in the textbox and then when he clicks out of the textbox , i want to hide the textbox and print whatever the user wrote in the textbox in the division(I am able to do that perfectly fine, but the problem lies ahead). Suppose if the user commits some mistake in typing, now what I want is I want that same textbox back when the user clicks back on that div. And then when again he clicks out of that textbox, the textbox should hide and the entered text should be printed in the div.

My HTML CODE:

```
 <html>
<body>
<div style="width:18px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;" id="filltheblank1" >  <input   type="text"  /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#filltheblank1").children(this).blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val()) {
      var entered = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
    }
    $(this).hide(500, function () {
      $(this).parent(this).html(entered).click(function () {
        //now what to do here. I want that when user clicks o the div, the textbox should come back and when he clicks out again, it should go away and the text he entered should be preinted

      });
    });
  });
});
```

please help someone

Comment: Don't really get it, but it should probably look more like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/FygJ7/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, i would add another div to show the text, with `display:none` to hide it the first time:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div style="width:18px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;" id="filltheblank1" >       
    <input type="text"  />
  </div>
  <div id="message" style="display:none"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then at the JS code you must improve the CSS selector to access the input element htm, this is how i would do it assuming there's only one input:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#filltheblank1 input").on('blur', function(){ //on is how it should be done on jQuery 1.7 and up
    if($(this).val()){
      var entered = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
    }
    $("#filltheblank1").fadeOut(500, function(){
     $("#message").html(entered);
     $("#message").show(); //shows hidden div
    }
 });

 //event to show the input when user clicks the div
 $("#message").on('click', function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $("#filltheblank1").fadeIn();
 });
});
```

I did to separate events to do what you want, and added ids to elements to make the javascript code easier and faster.

Comment: WOW you made it so easy. Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you Please explain me the meaning of $("#fillintheblank1 input") in the second line of the above code? Why have you written input there inside the bracket

Comment: $("#fillintheblank1 input") => you are targeting element of type 'input' anywhere inside #fillintheblank1 element

Comment: well Cool, One last question!! What if I wanna handle multiple textboxes(and hence, the divs corresponding to them) like this? Do I have to write code separately for each?

Comment: If you want to all of them to do the same, the current one works. If you want to do a differnt thing, you can use the jQuery.each() function and asign a general event to them, you can play with clasess and numbers (like .message-3) to make it work for each div/input